# Smooth lighting

Tags: rendering

Back in Blender 2.97b i used ambient occlusion as a shader on a box that surrounded my objects to give them that smooth light as shown in the posted picture.[image]
Since the 2.8 version this is no longer possible since the ambient occlusion no longer exist in the shader list.

Do you have any solution to my problem or do i have to go back to the old version again?

Thank you!
/John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is still **Ambient Occlusion** node in 2.80 but it's a bit different than 2.79 and it's under **Input** menu.

To be able to use it in **EEVEE** remember to turn on **Ambient Occlusion** in **Render settings**.

[image: final]